# How do I integrate a OpenSolaris NAS with AD?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, opensolaris, access-control-list, zfs

I basically want a OpenSolaris NAS (ZFS goodies) but I'd like to integrate it with AD, so that when I create a new user in AD, his roaming profile is created in the NAS. That means all his ACLs have to work (I know they're compatible), etc.

The tutorials I found don't actually work, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using FreeNAS (FreeBSD with ZFS)? It could make this alot easier for you.

Comment: Weird, suddenly I can't edit my own comments. Was going to add: "Or perhaps not, FreeNAS is considering a full re-write and upgrade to FreeBSD 8.0 to support ZFS in production systems."

Comment: Considered it, discarded it. Don't think ZFS on BSD is stable enough for production. Also, I'll either have to learn BSD or Solaris for this and Solaris seems to have a couple more advantages overall, IMHO.

edit: That and the company I work for want's to travel the solaris route, so I don't have much choice :P

Comment: OK. Well, I don't have an answer for you - but I atleast know that you'll need Samba with AD authentication.

Comment: http://blogs.sun.com/timthomas/entry/configuring_the_opensolaris_cifs_server

Comment: Thanks for the link, will try it.

BTW, as extra info, I've ran Sun Storage Server on a Vbox VM and the "connect to AD server" step didn't work either. If this does the trick, I'll post it here.

Comment: Talked to a friend of mine. Said he tried that tutorial a while ago and it doesn't work either. Will keep looking

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about whether or not the CIFS sharing feature in ZFS will do this, but you don't have to use that feature. Instead, if you use SAMBA to share the ZFS filesystems, you will have the full AD integration that SAMBA offers. That would be the way that I would solve this problem, and part of the reason is that people use SAMBA on Linux, FreeBSD and many other systems, so that their codebase will have fewer bugs in this area.

However, if you are following any SAMBA guides, do remember that ZFS works differently from common filesystems. Create one ZFS filesystem (or more) per user, i.e. don't use home directories on a single filesystem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I had already read something about this "one fs per user" and considering you can impose quotas on the fs (technically, limit the size of the fs itself), I was going to so just that.

In the meantime, one of the positive traits I've been reading about is the whole Windows style ACLs in ZFS and the ease to integrate a Solaris file server in a Win/Linux network. I was really hoping to use the CIFS export functionality, but it's always good to know I can go the SAMBA route. Thanks again.